# Filtering values in promql's predict_linear

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I would like to filter out certain values from the metric that `predict_linear` relies on.

Take the following example:
Ex: `predict_linear(some_metric[4h], 4 * 60 * 60) > 1024`

The `some_metric` in this case occasionally reports `-1` values, which I would like to filter out. (For reference, I am not in control of `some_metric`, this is reported by an external service)

I tried:

```
predict_linear((some_metric > 0)[4h], 4 * 60 * 60) > 1024
```

but this reports back:

```
Error executing query: 1:53: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is exactly as satiated in error mesage: ranges only allowed for vector selectors.

But you cab use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax, to workaround this issue.

```
predict_linear((some_metric > 0)[4h : ], 4 * 60 * 60) > 1024
```

Notice here `[4h:]` means range of 4 hours with minimal possible resolution. Since `:` is used it is recognised as subquery and can be applied not only to the vector selectors, but to the results of comparison (also, to functions and results of other binary operators)